# Remove Child Nodes Keep Their Parent

Tags: c#, xmldocument, xelement

I have XML Code Block as below (it is part of similar lines of hundreds..):

```
<specs>
    <spec name='fald' value = '100'>
        <name></name>
        <value></value>
    </spec>
</specs>
```

I need to convert code as seen below:

```
  <specs>
     <spec name ='fald' value = '100'/>
  </specs>
```

Using following code I am able to delete child nodes:

```
foreach (XElement child in doc.Descendants().Reverse())
{
    if (child.HasAttributes)
    {
        foreach (var attribute in child.Attributes())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.Value) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(child.Value))
                child.Remove();
        }
    }
}
```

But this process also deletes parent node ('spec') which is expected to  take place there. Any help is appreciated, thanks...

Comment: Did you paste the right code? Your code snippet doesn't delete any of the elements: see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kaPRtu)

Comment: Also, could you describe in a few words what the rules are in the result you want? Is the rule e.g. that "if a spec element has name and value attributes that are **not** empty, then delete its children"?

Comment: @Xerillio it deletes '<name></name>' because that child node has no attribute and no value, also deletes the child below, but then node 'spec' also is disappering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear what the criteria for deleting an element is, but to get you started, perhaps this is somewhere along the lines of what you are looking for?

```
var xml =
    @"<specs>
        <spec name='fald' value='100'>
          <name></name>
          <value></value>
        </spec>
      </specs>";

var doc = XElement.Parse(xml);

var childrenToDelete = doc.XPathSelectElements("//spec/*")
    .Where(elem => string.IsNullOrEmpty(elem.Value)
            && (!elem.HasAttributes
            || elem.Attributes().All(attr => string.IsNullOrEmpty(attr.Value))))
    .ToList();

foreach (var child in childrenToDelete)
{
    child.Remove();
}

// Produces:
// <specs>
//   <spec name="fald" value="100" />
// </specs>
```

Check [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/P7AyqS) for a test run.

Comment: thanks for your effort, but, name and value nodes are still there, which I want to remove, leaving only 'spec' with her attributes...

Comment: @biryaz check my update, does that work for you?

Comment: only accepted format is <specs><spec name="fald" value="100" /></specs> of hosting firm...

Comment: @biryaz I'm not sure I understand. Does the code not behave the way you are looking for? Try testing it on your own data. I just made some "random" example input since I didn't know much about the background.

Comment: code given above performs what I need, but problem is I do not know which node has this case as it is created by another part of code, for example below code is usefull for other type of nodes which will be deleted: "doc.Descendants().Where(e => string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value)).Remove();", therefore I can not supply node name or full path...

Comment: @biryaz I'm sorry but it's very difficult to tell what you need. You supplied very little information about the data you're working with and little information about what rules your "cleanup" should follow. If my answer is not acceptable, then please supply all the inputs and expected outputs by updating your question. I won't be able to help any further otherwise unfortunately.

Comment: somehow I will modify it to patch my demand, thanks, all the best...